# Query string encryption in angular and decrypt from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, asp.net-core

I want to encrypt my query string in Angular project and read it from asp.net page.

I have given my query string and AES encryption code below.

**Angular Code:-**

```
let lstrquerystring="username=visakah99$password=test";

let  iv2 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('Test123');
lstrcriptedtext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(lstrquerystring, 'Test123',
               { 
                keySize: 128 / 8,
                padding:CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding,
                iv: iv2}
                ).toString();

window.location.href="http://localhost:2081/validate.aspx?am="+lstrcriptedtext;
```

**.Net code**

```
var sEncryptionKey="Test123";
var cipherText=this is the query string;
var keybytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sEncryptionKey);
            var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sEncryptionKey);
var encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

  using (var rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                //Settings
                rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                rijAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;

                rijAlg.Key = key;
                rijAlg.IV = iv;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                var decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

                try
                {
                    // Create the streams used for decryption.
                    using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                    {
                        using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {

                            using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                            {
                                // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                                // and place them in a string.
                                plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                  
                    plaintext = "keyError";
                }
            }
```

But the plaintext response is "�����H.Y���k4Ew"�K>>B�p&�z�\u0090����_�\u0002\u000f�\u001eW�\n4�\u000e��\g믑ȱ�\rn�ⅼ\u0005��\u0002��K�\u001b��\a����!k>\u00171Y����6������#bw�ô���ܓ\t

How do we get above text readable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure encryption is the appropriate technology to use here? You're dealing with a password. Are you sure you need to be able to retrieve the plaintext of the password? Or do you just need to validate it, in which case a one way hash would be more secure than encryption?

Comment: Yes, .Net site is a separate site and I need to send username and password. Somehow, query string data is not decrypting correctly. decrypt plain text is not readable and it comes with �����H.Y

Comment: Are you planning to use HTTPS to access the other site? If so, it's already encrypted. It's not a good idea to put username and password in a URL (even the query string), even if it is encrypted. You're better off putting it in the body of the HTTP request, perhaps sending it as JSON.

Comment: Yes, New site has the HTTPS . But I am not sure the suggested way by you. Is there a any other better way to transfer data from angular site into a .net site and open in a different browser?

Comment: Hi @wiki, whether your application is an Asp.net core application or a traditional .Net Framework Web Form application? From the validate page url, it looks that a traditional Web Form application, right? Besides, from the response, it looks like the issue relates the data encoded format, when you decrypt the try to set the encode format. Here are an article about Encryption/Decryption, you could refer to it: [ES Encryption/Decryption With Angular 7](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/aes-encryptiondecryption-with-angular-7/)

Comment: What do you mean you're not sure about my suggestion? Which part are you not comfortable with? Do you understand what HTTPS is, and why it doesn't make sense to double encrypt the username and password? Do you understand why it's a bad idea to put the username and password in the URL?